# jquery querybuilder: editing the Rule's structure in the file query-builder.standalone

Tags: jquery-query-builder

**I created a custom plugin for Jquery Querybuilder but it only works if I edit the Rule's structure from the file querybuilder-standalone itself.**

The plugin I've created adds a button like the one from the plugin not-group inside each rule. The function of this plugin is to transform an input like this 'field = "value"' into this 'UPPER( field ) = "VALUE"'.
The problem with this solution is that, in order to reuse this query I need to modify the structure of the Rule itself in the query-builder.
The edits I would need to make are the following:

*You can find the original code at line 2242 of the file query-builder.standalone.js*

```
if (model.filter) {
    model.filter.to_upper = item.to_upper; /* <---This is the line I added myself */
    model.operator = self.getOperatorByType(item.operator, !options.allow_invalid);
    if (!model.operator) {
       model.operator = self.getOperators(model.filter)[0];
    }
}
```

And this:

*Original code between line 6215 and 6232*

```
var id = self.getSQLFieldID(field, value);
//The following line us the code I need
var to_upper = data.to_upper;
/**
* Modifies the rule generated from the SQL expression
* @event changer:sqlToRule
* @memberof module:plugins.SqlSupport
* @param {object} rule
* @param {object} AST
* @returns {object}
*/
var rule = self.change('sqlToRule', {
   id: id,
   field: field,
   operator: opVal.op,
   value: opVal.val,
   //The following line us the code I need
   to_upper: to_upper
}, data);
```

> 'to_upper' is a property I set to false by default and to true when its related button it's clicked.

**How could I do this without adding these code to query-builder itself?**

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find more details about my issue and the helpful answer I received from the creator of this UI component.
https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/931